# PHP email won't send to my email

Tags: php, forms, email, xampp

I have some problems with sending and receiving emails with my code..

When I try this code on my localhost(XAMPP) it says: Email send, but when i look in my mail i didn't receive the mail.. can someone help? My code:

```
<?php

// $EmailFrom = "ME";
$EmailTo = "My_amail_adress";
$Subject = "My_subject";
$Name = stripslashes($_POST['Name']); 
$Email = stripslashes($_POST['Email']); 
$Message = stripslashes($_POST['Message']); 

//setup the email
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body); //"From: <$EmailFrom>"

if ($success) {
    echo "Email send";
}
else{
    echo "Error, please try again";
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you set up email on your localhost?

Comment: What do you mean @putvande ??

Comment: Have you specified a mail server?

Comment: By default your localhost can't send email, you need to set that up first. Try Googling for 'email localhost'

Comment: As already suggested, you need to configure sendmail on your local system. Sending emails can be easily done with Mandrill or Mailgun, the advantage is that you can login and track the status of sent messages as well as other things.

Comment: oke i just find the map and the file: sendmail.ini.. so i found this:[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=mail.mydomain.com what i need to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have SMTP server configured in your localhost ?

You can send mail from localhost with sendmail package , sendmail package is inbuild in XAMPP. So if you are using XAMPP then you can easily send mail from localhost.

for example you can configure C:\xampp\php\php.ini and c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini for gmail to send mail.

in C:\xampp\php\php.ini find extension=php_openssl.dll and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

in php.ini file find [mail function] and change

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Now Open C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini. Replace all the existing code in sendmail.ini with following code

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

Now you have done!! create php file with mail function and send mail from localhost.

PS: don't forgot to replace my-gmail-id and my-gmail-password in above code. Also, don't forget to remove duplicate keys if you copied settings from above. For example comment following line if there is another sendmail_path : sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe" in the php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on `localhost` you can not send emails by default , you need to configure `sendmail`

[Try this tutorial](http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/)

Comment: It's just a link. Could you give more detail?